# Сохранение и чтение двумерного массива

Tags: массивы, delphi

Здравствуйте. Необходимо по нажатию кнопки 1 из stringgrid1 сохранить данные в файл, и загрузить их при нажатии кнопки 2 в stringgrid2. Как это лучше сделать?
Необходимо использовать двоичный файл.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Что значит "как"? Вам код написать что ли? Разбейте все на маленькие подзадачи, решите каждую в отдельности, потом соберите общее решение.

Comment: Да, код сохранения и код записи в файл. Самому написать не получается.

Comment: Здесь не выполняют работу *за Вас*. Покажите Ваш код, укажите в чем испытываете затруднения, и Вам, возможно, помогут, если Вы произведете впечатление человека, пытающегося научиться и сделать.